# How do I modify this css in Javascript NOT using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code in CSS that shows and hides the `login/register` page. Here is the CSS:

```
.form-module .form {
  display: none;
  padding: 40px;
}
.form-module .form:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

I'd like to write a function in JS that makes

- first (.form-module .form) change to "display: block;"
- second (.form-module .form:nth-child(2)) change to "display: none;"

If you have any idea how I can do this in JavaScript (not using the JQuery library) that would be very appreciated. I am still a noob with JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `querySelectorAll` function to implement it.
For example:

```
var activeFrm = false;
function toggleFrm() {
    activeFrm = !activeFrm;
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
    forms.forEach(function(form, ind) {
        switch (ind) {
            case 0: 
                form.style.display = activeFrm ? 'none' : 'block'; 
                break;
            case 1:
                form.style.display = activeFrm ? 'block' : 'none'; 
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

And you can also use the `querySelector` function if you don't want to run through a loop. 
For example:

```
document.querySelector('.form').style.display = 'block';
document.querySelector('.form:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: This works great to switch one way, but I can't get it to switch back. It's meant to be a toggle back and forth between both. Thanks for everything so far though!!

Comment: You need to manipulate the `display` value that each `form` gets, on every single click. How about using a variable named, for example, `activeFrm` and toggle it's value from `0` to `1` for each click, and of course check it's value before changing the element's `display` value.

Comment: Sorry for the bother but how exactly would I do this. I am a noob with javascript so I'm a bit confused, but you have been very helpful so far!!

Comment: I edited my post. Toggle the `toggleFrm` function within a button click or whatever you want :)

Comment: Yay, it works!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var loginForm = document.querySelector('.form-module');
var registerForm = document.getElementsByClassName('form-module')[1];

(function(){
    loginForm.style.display = "block";
})();

(function(){
    registerForm.style.display = "none";
})();
```

Comment: This works great to switch one way, but I can't get it to switch back. It's meant to be a toggle back and forth between both. Thanks for everything so far though!!

Answer (score 0):

As for now, You can make use of the style property on any HTML element.

For example:

```
const myElm = document.querySelector("#myelm");

myElm.style.background = "red";
```

For further information, checkout the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a matter of targeting both forms and setting their styles within the function using a combination of `style` and `display`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  toggleForms();
  
  function toggleForms() {
    document.querySelector('.form-module form:first-child').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.form-module form:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
.form-module .form {
  display: none;
  padding: 40px;
}

.form-module .form:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-module">
  <form class="form">
    <legend>Login</legend>
  </form>

  <form class="form">
    <legend>Register</legend>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Would really appreciate a reason why this was downvoted. OP clearly asked for **one** function that toggles the visibility and this answer does exactly that.

Comment: I am not sure who gave you a down vote. I have not downvoted anything and your answer isn't wrong. I can upvote it to make it even.